# Xcode: simulators shows correct xib interface, but on device, it's showing old interface

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Xcode shows old, deleted xib files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3765989/xcode-shows-old-deleted-xib-files)

My problem is: I have updated one of the xib file in Xcode, it works well for iPhone/iPad simulators, but when I try to run on device (iPhone), it still shows the old interface.

I have tried delete the app on device, clean the project in Xcode and run it on device again. For several times. But still showing old xib file UI.

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions:
 1. Look into your localized xib files - maybe you have forgotten one
 2. Clear dervived data.

Answer (score 0):

If clean project target and reinstall not work, try to change your device's locale setting or reboot it.