# Old interface displayed after Application update

Tags: ios, xcode

Sometimes, i have strange behaviour while running new version of my applications (native ios application, developed under XCode 4.3).

It seems like some old interface parts displayed, while running new version of application.

It occurs on IOS simulator and on real device, connected to developer machine.

Deleting Derived data doesnt help. Cleaning sources doesnt help.
Deleting and Reinstalling application **helps**, but i afraid what some users can see old interface.

How to be totally sure what users will see new interface ?

I took a look on similiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5714372/how-to-empty-caches-and-clean-all-targets-xcode-4) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12236450/xcode-simulators-shows-correct-xib-interface-but-on-device-its-showing-old-i) but didnot found answer - how to be sure what users will see new interface after application update. Reinstaling application is not solution.

Comment: Making "touch" (to change modification time) to all .xib, .m, *.h doesnt help either. It is time to start bounty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont think you need to worry about this happening when updating through the App Store, as the actual app update procedure is that the update is installed to a new directory, then user documents are copied over, then the old app is deleted.
Better described here [What precisely happens when iOS installs an update to an app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5225974/what-precisely-happens-when-ios-installs-an-update-to-an-app)

Answer (score 1):

I know for sure that deleted or renamed resource files (like .xib files or images) remain in the bundle on the device or simulator, even if you clean/rebuild the xcode project.

The only way to make sure those files are gone completely, is to remove the app from the home screen, like you described. So I think the undeleted files could be part of your problem.

Also check if you have changed something about the localized .xib files or .strings files.

I'm pretty sure, that if the problem goes away when you delete the app from the home screen, then no end user will encounter your unwanted interface parts.

Comment: The issue occurs on changed files. They wasnt deleted or localized between builds. It seems they wasnt overwritten, or has been cached. Also, it may has relation to built-in git client - changes was pushed on another computer and pulled here.

Comment: Im not sure if there is a way to delete application from itself while or before upgrading.